# Can product of two symmetric positive definite matrices yield a matrix with all zero eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us say A and B are symmetric positive definite matrices. Can their product AB have **all zero eigenvalues**? I am trying to come up with an example but I always got positive definite matrices as a result. I have seen the theorem that the product cannot have negative eigenvalues but I struggle to find an example of zero eigenvalue case.

Comment: We have the following results: A matrix is invertible if and only if  $0$ is not an eigenvalue. The product of two invertible matrices is invertible. And lastly: positive definite matrices, also called PSD, are invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. In fact, if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, then $AB$ cannot have **any** zero eigenvalues.

A matrix will have zero as an eigenvalue if and only if it is singular. However, positive definite matrices are non-singular, and the product of non-singular matrices  is always non-singular.

Comment: To the person who voted to delete my post (and who I suspect also voted to close the question): I think that this question gives sufficient context: *"I am trying to come up with an example but I always got positive definite matrices as a result. I have seen the theorem that the product cannot have negative eigenvalues but I struggle to find an example of zero eigenvalue case."* The asker gives the theorem that inspired this line of inquiry and explains that they have tried to generate an example.

Comment: I am sorry if I asked the question in the wrong way... Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Emre I think that your question is fine, but apparently someone disagrees. In any case, you're welcome. If you're curious about why the voter might not like your question, see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about the standards for a "good question" on this site and what "context" should be included.